# can't download nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm using nuget and I try download some packages. But it doesn't work. 
For instanse, I use this command

```
Install-Package System.Web.Http
```

And I receive this error

```
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'System.Web.Http'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Web.Http
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I fix it by

```
Install-Package System.Web.Http -Source nuget.org
```

And I receive another error

```
Install-Package : The remote name could not be resolved: 'az320820.vo.msecnd.net'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Web.Http -Source nuget.org
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I unchecked field "Act as system proxy on findler.

Moreover, I don't hava access from chrome to http://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/castle.core.3.3.0.nupkg

Few days ago I downloaded packages without any problems and nothing change after this in system configuration.

Can anybody help me?. Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart VS (or ideally the computer) after changing the Fiddler settings? (I'd run without Fiddler *at all* for this...)

Comment: Yes. I restarted system. I ran without findler too.

Comment: Same problem round here, have you solved yours???? Thanks

Comment: I reinstalled VS. Besides, you can clean VS cache, but I don't know if it'll help.